# Python line needs explaining please

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have recently taken a online tutorial for python and I was given these lines of code:

```
n = int(input())

a = [[abs(i - j) for j in range(n)] for i in range(n)]
```

Please can someone explain what they mean. Thanks Adam!!

Comment: Do you have a good Python reference book or site you can visit that helps explain these things? I used books [like this](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920028154.do) but there's many, many other options.

Comment: I recommend to print each single part; that will help you to understand what is going on.

Comment: We don't know how much you know already, so this question is too broad. Explain what you already understand and where exactly you are stuck.

Comment: How would I do that Cleb I think that would help!

Comment: Python has a REPL -- enter it in as you would any experiment in python.

Comment: Python comes with an interactive interpreter. You can type those commands into the interpreter and see what they do. Then you can experiment with them to learn more. Apart from the Python documentation there is also builitin help: try typing `help(input)` for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to understand the code is to run it and see what's happening step by step. To help you get started:

The first line is reading an `int` from user input:

```
n = int(input())
```

The second line is using list comprehension:

```
a = [[abs(i - j) for j in range(n)] for i in range(n)]
```

Which can be translated with for loop as follows:

```
a = []
for i in range(n):
    tmp = []
    for j in range(n):
        tmp.append(abs(i - j))
    a.append(tmp)
```

Read about the following (google is your friend):

- list comprehension
- range()
- input()

Answer (score 0):

The first row takes an input from the user and casts it into an int(number) and saves it in a var `n`.

The second row, creates a list which has `n` sublists and each sublist has `n` elements like:

> [[0, 1, 2, 3], [1, 0, 1, 2], [2, 1, 0, 1], [3, 2, 1, 0]]

Comment: I understand the first part however I don’t understand how the numbers in the subset are produced

Comment: there are 2 for loops, each with an iterator, i and j. the numbers in the sublists are a result of the absolute difference of the iterators abs(i-j)

Answer (score 0):

OK, so taking it in sections

```
        input()
```

get a number entered by the user at the keyboard

```
n = int(input())
```

Get the number rather than having it as a string of characters, store it in 'n'

The next line is list comprehension, which has the basic form

```
    [{something to do for each value} {a range of values}]
```

So breaking down the code line

```
    [                                for i in range(n)]
```

Get 'n' numbers, starting at 0, so if n is 3, you will get [0, 1, 2].  These numbers will be in 'i'

```
    [[            for j in range(n)] for i in range(n)]
```

For each value of 'i', also do this for each value in the range in 'j'.

```
    [[abs(i - j) for j in range(n)] for i in range(n)]
```

For every i and j, return the absolute value (the positive amount) of the difference between i and j

```
a = [[abs(i - j) for j in range(n)] for i in range(n)]
```

For each 'i' you will get a list of the difference between i and each value of j.  So you will get a list of lists.

For n=3, you will get

```
[[0, 1, 2], [1, 0, 1], [2, 1, 0]]
```